# what does "+incompatible" suffix mean in Go github versions?

Tags: version-control, version, versioning, go-github

I am considering upgrading go-github from `v17.0.0+incompatible` to `v28`

I notice some [versions that go-github released](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-github/v28@v28.0.0/github?tab=versions) has a `+incompatible` suffix, especially for the `v1` category. What does that entail? I am guessing version with `+incompatible` are incompatible with the newer/older version?

In general, when updating a third party dependency, how can I know if upgrading to the newer version is safe? Do I just have to read through the change logs?

Answer (score 0):

Go in general does not want you to use the same import path for multiple incompatible versions of a project.  This is so that one dependency can use one major version of a module and another dependency can use another.

This syntax indicates that the repository is not using a suffix for their module paths for a non-v0, non-v1 version, and bypasses the logic in the module code that does semantic import versioning.  The documentation about this functionality is [available on the Go website](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_compatibility_and_semantic_versioning).

Since going from one major version to another is a breaking change in semantic versioning, you'll need to determine out of band whether or not they're compatible.  The `+incompatible` suffix doesn't implicitly denote this, but going from v17 to v28 does.  So changelogs might be a good idea, or you could just update and run your tests if you're confident in your testsuite.

Answer (score 0):

The `+incompatible` suffix in `go.mod` is used when Go Modules is dealing with a dependency that is not a Go module, i.e. it doesn't have a `go.mod` file.

This usually occurs when you are importing a package that has not yet adopted Go Modules or is in a version that predates the adoption of Go Modules. Go Modules can still work with these packages, but the +incompatible suffix is added to indicate that the package is not a Go module.